# For loop is not looping data individually

Tags: bash

I am trying to loop through some data that I filtered for. However it only loops through it once as a whole.

My example data:

```
1.1G user1
2.2G user2
3.3G user3
```

What it is doing:

```
1.1
2.2
3.3
hi
```

What I want it to do:

```
1.1
hi
2.2
hi
3.3
hi
```

Here is what I am using:

```
hdSize=$(du -h --max-depth=1 /home/users | awk '$1~/T|G/' | sed '$d')
gbSize=$(echo $hdSize | awk '{print $1}' | tr -d "G")

for sizeAlert in $gbSize
do
    echo $sizeAlert
    echo "hi"
done
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using bash - not zsh for example (which would not split `$gbSize` on whitespace by default)?

Comment: Yes I am using bash. OS is RHEL 7.8

Comment: If I put hdSize in the for loop it works. however gbSize does not.

Comment: Welcome to SE: please mark your accepted response with a green check mark to signal others that it is helpful. Read https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers.

Comment: Got it to work by putting print $1 first before $1~/G/. Like this— hdSize=$(du -h --max-depth=1 /home/users  | awk '{print $1}' | awk '$1~/T|G/' | sed '$d')

Answer (score 3):

If you're running Bash, `echo $hdSize` will split the variable on whitespace, and combine the parts with spaces, effectively folding everything to a single line. You'll get just one field out of the pipeline.

If, instead, you're running Zsh, or your `IFS` is set to empty, the variable will not be split and the pipeline should work as intended. On the other hand, in those cases, `$gbSize` is also not split for the `for` loop, which then only runs once.

You could fix that first case in Bash by quoting the variable for the second pipeline so that the newlines would stay intact: `echo "$hdSize" | ...`. But that's still not very nice.

Assuming you want to do something with the directory names too, you would need a loop where you get both at the same time. That's simplest to do by piping the output from `du` to a `while` loop running `read`, which can split the fields from the line to variables:

```
du -BG --max-depth=1 /home/users | sed -e '$d' -e 's/G/ /' |
while read size dir; do 
    printf "directory %s is %d gigs\n" "$dir" "$size";
    if [ "$size" -gt 1024 ]; then
        printf "that's a lot.\n"
    fi
done
```

I used `du -BG` to always get the size in gigabytes regardless of the value. It makes comparisons and arithmetic easier.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work by putting print $1 first before $1~/G/.

hdSize=$(du -h --max-depth=1 /home/users | awk '{print $1}' | awk '$1~/T|G/' | sed '$d')

Comment: Better to combine the `awk`'s: `awk '$1 ~ /[TG]/ { print $1 }'`